# Prefixing console ouput of system calls from Ruby

Tags: ruby, unix

I'd like to create a Ruby script that prefixes the console output. For example:

I want to implement an interface like this:

```
puts 'MainLogger: Saying hello'
prefix_output_with('MainLogger') do
  system 'echo hello'
end
```

So this shows up in the console:

```
MainLogger: Saying hello
MainLogger: hello
```

What would be a good approach to prefix all of the syscall output to have some logger?

Note: I don't care if we echo what the system call is or not

Comment: First, if you want to do a "system" logger, look at using either Ruby's built-in [Logger](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/logger/rdoc/index.html) or [Syslog](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/syslog/rdoc/index.html) classes, which have all sorts of bells and whistles. Read through their documentation a couple times as there is a lot of capability. The second thing is, it really looks like you're asking us to write code for you since you don't show anything that works along the lines of what you're asking about. Finally, using `system 'echo hello'` is no better than `puts 'hello'`

Comment: I was really looking for more of advice for an approach than actual code. The two classes you linked and the answer below will be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point here is that there's no way to know if `system` will actually produce output. I'm assuming you don't want a blank `MainLogger:` whenever a system call doesn't print anything, so you'll need to do the prefixes in the shell:

```
def prefix_system_calls pre
  sys = Kernel.instance_method(:system)
  # redefine to add prefix
  Kernel.send(:define_method, :system) do |cmd|
    sys.bind(self)["#{cmd} | sed -e 's/^/#{pre}: /'"]
  end

  yield
  # redefine to call original method
  Kernel.send(:define_method, :system) do |*args|
    sys.bind(self)[*args]
  end
end

system "echo foo"
prefix_system_calls("prefix") do
  system "echo bar"
end
system "echo baz"
# foo
# prefix: bar
# baz
```

This implementation is pretty fragile, though. It doesn't handle [all the different ways you can call `system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system), and prefixes containing special shell characters could cause an error.

Comment: Okay I figured I had to do it at the shell level so I'll investigate that a bit